# Standard deviation of estimator to predict age

Tags: regression

Hi all I thought I understood regression but this question has me stumped.

Suppose we have two independent models to predict someone’s age. From experience
we know that the first estimator has a standard deviation of 1 around the true value, the
second has a std deviation of 2. If you wanted to predict someone’s age given these
estimators, how would you do it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a homework question, what have you already tried yourself to solve the question?

Comment: @Oxbowerce, yes it was a homework question asked a while ago, just trying to solve it, in terms of what I have done, I have gone back to my uni books which did not help if you intend to close it no worries, can you at least point me in a direction that would at least help me understand the question. The only idea I have right now is an ensemble. Thanks.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind it to check the outputs of the two models and see what the overlap is between the predicted values plus the standard deviations as this is where the real value should be located.

Comment: Thanks for this

Comment: No worries, you can probably even use the density properties of the distribution of the standard deviations to get the value that has the highest probability.

Comment: In terms of this question, I understand that the model to predict age would be a regression model. My question is what exactly is the estimator of a model is it the same as the prediction.

Comment: When the question refers to an "estimator" it simply means a model that will estimate/predict a value given certain inputs. A regression model is an example of such an estimator.